# Laravel routing - relative path issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
docs
  - index.php
  - js/
  - css/
  - img/
mylaravelapp
  - app/
  - bootstrap/
  - config/
  - database/
  - public/
  - resources/
  - storage/
  - tests/
  - etc.
```

What I want to happen is that when a user navigates to:

http://localhost/myprojects/mylaravelapp/public/docs

They get served all files from my "docs" folder (including all the javascript, css and images...)

I tried:

- putting a symlink to ../../docs inside the "public" folder (didn't work - I get a "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." error)
- .htaccess rules such as `RewriteRule ^docs/(.*) {REQUEST_FILENAME}/../../docs/$1 [L]` but I'm struggling here...

Can I somehow do this in routes.php? I think having all this in my routes.php file would suit me best.

Something like:

`Route::get('docs', 'DocsController@index');`

But how to return a reference to a folder not in the public directory?

I'm really new to Laravel, so please go easy on me...

Answer (score 2):

Why do you make "docs" folder outside from your app?

In this situation, if you have directory "docs" outside from "mylaravelapp", than Your link will be like this:

http://localhost/myprojects/docs

but I think this is not good architecture solution